# unable to login on appcelerator studio (windows pc 64bit)

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

After filling up the details this form keeps popping up.

[image]

Comment: might be id/password is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Most probably problem might be with your login credentials/internet connection.

However,you can also login from CLI to avoid login screen during the studio startup.

```
$ appc login
```

Comment: It says "You are not the member of any active organization.Please contact with administrator or support team "http://prnt.sc/bzqp0t

Comment: I believe you are under trial plan/free plan and that would have been expired. Just to confirm, please login into http://platform.appcelerator.com/ and verify your account status. If it's inactive - that means, plan is expired.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to log in to Appcelerator you need to have internet connection. If your internet connection is Ok and you still have the issue in logging in try troubleshooting as described in documentation. If this does not solve the issue you can contact in Appcelerator intercom.

[Documentation Link](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Errors_Logging_In_to_Studio)